# How to change background image of div gradually with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I would like to fade out the opacity of one image and then fade in another. The background was added in CSS, is this possible.

Edit:

```
  //Current changing mechanism, change is instant.
  document.getElementById('fade').style.backgroundImage="url(flickrIcon.png)";
```

Is it possible to use something like:

```
document.getElementById("fade").style.backgroundImage.opacity = (e.g, 0.8);
```

And then manipulate the opacity with an interval function?

Comment: OK, so where is your attempt so far?

Comment: It's possible. Search other questions and try to find an answer and post what you tried.

Comment: My attempt so far is instantly changing the image with JS

Comment: Look at jQuery fading API http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Comment: Basically I am wondering if you can change the backgroundImage opacity of a div with DOM scripting Js

Answer (score 0):

There's no opacity option to css background.

You have to first fade the opacity, then switch out the bg image and then fade back in.  If you want to crossfade, you'll have to use two elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: I have decided to use a gif to illustrate the change.